# Update password with postPersist($object) method SonataAdminBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, sonata-admin

I need to update password with sonata admin int fos userbundle 'bcrypt' password.

This is my admin class,

```
<?php

namespace AdminBundle\Admin;

use Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\ListMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Datagrid\DatagridMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Form\FormMapper;
use Sonata\AdminBundle\Show\ShowMapper;

class UserAdmin extends Admin {
    public function postPersist($object) {
        $userManager = $this->get('fos_user.user_manager');
        $user = $userManager->findUserBy(array('id'=>$object->id));
        $user->setPlainPassword('test');
        $userManager->updateUser($user);

    }
```

This is my user entity,

```
<?php

// src/AppBundle/Entity/User.php

namespace AdminBundle\Entity;

use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="telephone", type="text", length=30, nullable=false)
     */
    private $telephone;

    /**
     * Set nonotification
     *
     * @param text $telephone
     * @return User
     */
    public function settelephone($telephone) {
        $this->telephone = $telephone;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get telephone
     *
     * @return text
     */
    public function gettelephone() {
        return $this->telephone;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="text", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * Set nonotification
     *
     * @param text $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setname($name) {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get name
     *
     * @return text
     */
    public function getname() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="text", length=60, nullable=false)
     */
    private $surname;

    /**
     * Set nonotification
     *
     * @param text $name
     * @return User
     */
    public function setsurname($surname) {
        $this->surname = $surname;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get surname
     *
     * @return text
     */
    public function getsurname() {
        return $this->surname;
    }

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }

}
```

But I'm getting this error instead,

> Attempted to call an undefined method named "get" of class
>   "AdminBundle\Admin\UserAdmin". Did you mean to call e.g.
>   "getActiveSubClass", "getActiveSubclassCode", "getBaseCodeRoute",
>   "getBaseControllerName", "getBaseRouteName", "getBaseRoutePattern",
>   "getBatchActions", "getBreadcrumbs", "getChild", "getChildren",
>   "getClass", "getClassnameLabel", "getCode", "getConfigurationPool",
>   "getCurrentChild", "getCurrentChildAdmin", "getDataSourceIterator",
>   "getDatagrid", "getDatagridBuilder", "getExportFields",
>   "getExportFormats", "getExtensions", "getFilterFieldDescription",
>   "getFilterFieldDescriptions", "getFilterParameters", "getFilterTheme",
>   "getForm", "getFormBuilder", "getFormContractor",
>   "getFormFieldDescription", "getFormFieldDescriptions",
>   "getFormGroups", "getFormTabs", "getFormTheme", "getIdParameter",
>   "getLabel", "getLabelTranslatorStrategy", "getList", "getListBuilder",
>   "getListFieldDescription", "getListFieldDescriptions",
>   "getManagerType", "getMaxPageLinks", "getMaxPerPage",
>   "getMenuFactory", "getModelManager", "getNewInstance",
>   "getNormalizedIdentifier", "getObject", "getObjectIdentifier",
>   "getObjectMetadata", "getParent", "getParentAssociationMapping",
>   "getParentFieldDescription", "getPerPageOptions",
>   "getPermissionsShow", "getPersistentParameter",
>   "getPersistentParameters", "getRequest", "getRoot", "getRootCode",
>   "getRouteBuilder", "getRouteGenerator", "getRouterIdParameter",
>   "getRoutes", "getSecurityHandler", "getSecurityInformation",
>   "getShow", "getShowBuilder", "getShowFieldDescription",
>   "getShowFieldDescriptions", "getShowGroups", "getShowTabs",
>   "getSideMenu", "getSubClasses", "getSubject", "getTemplate",
>   "getTemplates", "getTranslationDomain", "getTranslationLabel",
>   "getTranslator", "getUniqid", "getUrlsafeIdentifier" or
>   "getValidator"?

It would be great help someone can look into it.

Comment: You shouldn't be updating a password in an event. You will save yourself a lot of headaches and problems if you simply set the password when you need to change it; Please check this slide show: http://ocramius.github.io/doctrine-best-practices/#/47

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access the container with `$this->get('service.name')` from a sonata admin class. You should use:

```
$container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
$userManager = $container->get('fos_user.user_manager');
```

Also, I don't know if your solution would work anyway. I would use something like this:

```
public function postPersist($object) {
    $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
    $entityManager = $container->get('doctrine.orm.entity_manager');
    $object->setPlainPassword('test');
    $entityManager->persist($user);
    $entityManager->flush();
}
```

And do yourself a favor and respect the naming conventions (`getName` instead of `getname`, etc)